# joomla ajax component development multiple functions

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, joomla, mootools

I have a component which works fine using AJAX and mootools.  Currently the **view.raw.php** only has one function in it which is display.  I've been trying to create other functions within the component to use from AJAX but I can't make it work.

I thought that the ajax call is:

```
url: 'index.php?option=com_optical_database&view=gender&task=hello&format=raw',
```

with a public function within the component called hello:

```
public function hello(){
```

but it ignores this and goes to the display function every time.  Is there a way of avoiding this?

Comment: can you post more code from the php file?

Comment: have you tried only: index.php?option=com_optical_database&task=hello and in hello method just die('-');?

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the place where the GET parameter `task` is used.

In Joomla there is usually a `switch` statement for this, and when you want to define a new `task`, you first need to add a new `case` in this `switch`.